# How to initialize an array of struct in C++ while specifying array index explicitly

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am a little new to C++ and learning the language. Right now I'm using C++17 and GCC.
I have the following `struct` named `Spec` in my C++ code.

```
struct Spec
{
    int val;
    double otherVal;
};
```

And I have an `array` named `specData` of these structs. I know in advance (at compile time) the values of the structs in my array.
Thus, I can initialize my array as follows:

```
Spec specData[] = { 
        { .val = 1, .otherVal = 3.56 }, 
        { .val = 3, .otherVal = 9.88 },
    } ;
```

However, the index of each entry is important. I want to explicitly map each element in the array with some index which I will be giving an int-alias so it is clear to which subject each `Spec` belongs. In my code, I can then easily access the `specData` using the int-alias also. (My intent is that this helps to ease maintenance and to make it less error prone).

Suppose I have an `Spec` for each of these entries (this could be my int-alias for example):

```
enum class Items
{
    ITEM_NAME1   = 0,
    ANOTHER_ITEM = 1,
};
```

Then, I want to initialize my array something like this:

```
Spec specData[] = { 
        [Items::ITEM_NAME1]   = { .val = 1, .otherVal = 3.56 }, 
        [Items::ANOTHER_ITEM] = { .val = 3, .otherVal = 9.88 },
    } ;
```

This obviously does not compile.

I know it seems like I might better use: `std::map<Items, Spec>`.
Altough that would probably work, however, `map` has an `O(log N)` complexity, while an array look-up is `O(1)` complexity.
I will be looking up lots of values, so I would like to have the extra speed.

Is it possible to initialize my array like the way I want?
If not, what is the second best alternative?

Comment: With the code shown, the value of each mapped enum is also the array's index.  You could simply use the enum as the index.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<int, Spec>` has O(1) lookup. So you could use that. Obviously it's not as fast as an array though. So it's a case of what you want to compromise, speed or safety.

Comment: Can you use assignment? `entrySpecification specificationData[MAX_ITEMS_COUNT]; specificationData[Items::ITEM_NAME1]   = { .val = 1, .otherVal = 3.56 }; specificationData[Items::ANOTHER_ITEM] = { .val = 3, .otherVal = 9.88 };`

Comment: BTW, [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) are C++20, not C++17.

Comment: @DrewDormann That is exactly my aim :). I edited the question and clarified.

Comment: @john, I think I don't agree. All element access are noted [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) as logarithmic in container size.

Comment: @Stefan your comment link is for `std::map`, not [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which john was referencing.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks! But I cannot upgrade this project to C++20 right now. But thanks anyway, good to know! Because it seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: I meant that your claim: *"I can initialize my array as follows: [..]`{ .val = 1, .otherVal = 3.56 }`"* is not C++17.

Comment: @Jardo42 That is interesting. I have `CFLAGS = -std=c++17` in my makefile so I figured I'm compiling using C++17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `constexpr` method and manually assign the entries one-by-one. Its all evaluated at compile time, so it's not any slower.

```
constexpr std::array<Spec, 2> make_spec_data() {
    std::array<Spec, 2> array{};
    array[(int)Items::ITEM_NAME1] = { 1, 3.56 };
    array[(int)Items::ANOTHER_ITEM] = { 3, 9.88};
    return array;
}
constexpr std::array<Spec, 2> specificationData = make_spec_data();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm studying it. I like the approach and it is what I am looking for. One think I noticed is that the compiler gives this error: `error: uninitialized variable 'array' in 'constexpr' function`. I'm no expert on `constexpr` but it seems declaring a variable and initializing it later like you do in a `constexpr` function is not allowed?

Comment: *"Typo"* -> `std::array<Spec, 2> array{};` (for `constexpr`).

Comment: @Stefan ah, I'm not quite as practiced with `constexpr` as I wish I were

Comment: Thanks, there are some more typo's, I will fix them in the answer (as soon as SO lets me). Or @MooingDuck you can do it. `return array` is missing, and the enums inside the array `[ ]`-operator need to be cast to `int`. It seems to be working with these changes. I will test some more and accept the answer. I'm still open for other approaches tough

Comment: @MooingDuck Hi, this seems to work great! I made your `make_spec_data` in a lambda and replaced some of the type with `auto` to make it compacter. One thing is bothering me though, is is possible to not specify the array size manually? To get it from the `enum` or better let it follow from the array initialization?

Comment: @Stefan: There's a couple tricks that people use to auto-determine the array size, but I dislike them.  The most common is `enum Items { ITEM_NAME1, ANOTHER_ITEM, ITEM_COUNT}` and then `std::array<Spec, ITEM_COUNT>`. With an `enum class` that gets even more ugly.